# Creating a Goldberg polyhedron in Blender

Tags: modeling, faces

currently I am working on a game idea for Unity and I want to use Blender as my modeling software for it.
The surface of my sphere like planet consists of separate tiles like you can see in this Goldberg polyhedron example:

https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10cD

By reading other posts from this community I was able to shape the polyhedron into a sphere but then realized after cutting out the separate tiles, that they were not proper hexagons or pentagons. With this type of polyhedron this should actually be possible.
Now I looked back at the model and found out, that the hexagonal and pentagonal faces actually are not proper flat surface but their vertices are somewhat off and this caused my tiling to make slightly deformed hexagons and pentagons.

Is there a way to create this and more complicated polyhedrons maybe in Blender itself, in which the surface tiles actually form a flat surface without some vertices sticking slightly out?

Thanks in advance.

**// Edit**
So I used the geodesic dome addon which can now be found under the extra objects addon.

I tried to cut out the single tiles but again the edges a weirdly formed.
[image]

I do not understand why it gives me these odd shapes after I subdivide the faces and cast a sphere modifier. The original geodesic dome has the proper proportions which are now somewhat altered.

Sorry for my bad english.

**// Edit**
Apparently I simply selected the wrong faces... maybe I should should make more frequent use of my brain^^

[image]

Should have realised that using the first approach I would get far to many tiles for the geodesic dome I was using... 
Luckily it looks now far more like a football.

Thank you so much for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 6):

Yes in fact, there is an addon for unusual geometric Objects.
[image: Goldberg Polyhedron]

1. Enable the Geodesic Domes2 Addon in the Preferences.
   [image: Userpreferences]
2. Add a Geodesic Object
   [image: Add Object]
3. Configure the Geodesic Object as shown. (class2 increses the "subdivision")
   [image: Configure Geodesic Object]
4. If you create those shapes often, just add a preset. You won't have to specify all parameters every time
   [image: Add Preset]
5. The nomrals are flipped, so go in EditMode and press [shift + N] to recalculate them.
   [image: Flip Normals]

Comment: That looks perfect. Probably am goind to try to use this approach for testing if such a game even makes any sense ^^. But could I also use this to generate more complex Goldberg polyhedrons as shown here? https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A100ccD

Comment: So I tried creating the geodesic domes and everything works splendidly. But when I try to generate the bend hexagonal and pentagonal tilings they have weirdly formed edges. Just as with the polygon I downloaded from the website.